# Is there a solution to show the variable in printf on mac?

Tags: c

I was using mac's terminal to compile .c file.
terminal instruction as flow:
gcc output0.c;
./a.out;

### code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    n = 1;
    printf("fix 3: %c \n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

---

result as flow:
fix 3:

question: why the variable 1 is not displayed.

MacOs Version：10.13.4 high sierra

gcc info：
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: `%c` is a format for a char not an int (`%i`), and `0x01` is not a printable character, it is a control character for "start of header"

Comment: `1 != '1'`.  This is a good opportunity to understand why!

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with you being on a Mac. The *format specifier* states how to interpret the value being printed on screen. The `%c` format specifier interprets the value being printed as the ASCII code of an ASCII character set. That is, it will print the character whose ASCII code matches the value of `n`. In this case, `n = 1` is the ASCII code for a non printable character known as *start of header*, that's why you don't see it. [Here's](https://www.systutorials.com/4670/ascii-table-and-ascii-code/) the full ASCII table and more info. Try changing your format specifier to `%i` for integers. And also check [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for info on `printf` and other format specifiers.